# In app purchase : error thread 1 signal sigabrt

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

This is something new I experience in In-app purchase.I could retrieve my product from there when I tap the button to purchase it throws me a exception like "thread 1 signal sigabrt"
and the console prints the following:

```
2013-12-06 16:40:16.641 sample[384:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot finish a purchasing transaction'
```

After tapping my purchase button ,

```
- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender {
     SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];
     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment]; 
}
```

it moves to update transactions , there

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {

        switch (transaction.transactionState) {

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

                [self UnlockPurchase];

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];


                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                            default:
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"purchasing");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

                break;
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]removeTransactionObserver:self];
        }
    }
}
```

Now the break point moves straight to `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing` and the exception throws.I have a restore button, using that I can restore the items back no issue it works.But trying to purchase once again using test account throws this error.Before many times I repurchased I received a alert showing "Do yo want to purchase this again" but now it fails.Is this due to using test accounts too many times ?

Another Issue, before throwing this exception I found many times after starting the app (in few sec)it shows me alert view to login(test user acc) and after tapping the "buyProduct" my purchase it shows my second test accounts and just after entering into my purchase controller view.I've placed this `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:_purchaseController];`in `viewDidLoad`. Is that correct ? It really annoys that login alert pop up around multiple times when I want to buy(on working state) but now straightly throws this error.

I have testing In-app using 3 test accounts more than week Is that a problem ? why this exception throws and whats the reason it asks multiple time login alert ? Please help !

Comment: is your device jail broken?

Comment: no ! In app worked fine for me more than a week I got this error for past two days.

Comment: don't do anything in SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing.. just break

Comment: Please check your bundle identifier and and in AppPurchase key 
Is it proper or not?

Comment: @keyurbhalodiya yes its correct. I haven't changed anything regarding my codes.

Comment: sometime there server becomes down for maintenance or with no reason :(, at that moment developer portion of apple server stops working, We have to postpone our release for 3 days because of this. may be you are facing same issue. keep digging the issue as well as checkout either apple is down for maintenance or not...

Comment: oh thanks ! Actually I tested another sample In app demo in Xcode,When I try make a purchase it showed me the following **2013-12-06 18:56:13.694 sample_purchase[505:60b] Transaction Failed
2013-12-06 18:56:20.553 sample_purchase[505:60b] <SKPaymentQueue: 0x166809c0>: Ignoring restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername: because already restoring transactions
2013-12-06 18:56:21.844 sample_purchase[505:60b] <SKPaymentQueue: 0x166809c0>: Ignoring restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername: because already restoring transactions **

Comment: Have you ever got the end of it please? We are suffering from this at the moment and can not find any reasonable way out of it.

Comment: @ZoltanMagyar Create a new test user account for In app. Sign out from old test user in iPhone settings-> iTunes & App Store. Delete app in iPhone.Restart iPhone & Xcode. If issue persists try to delete and re add new provision. Make sure your product list is retrieved correctly in "didReceiveResponse" !